# Responding to startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android

I am trying to respond to a result from an activity using startActivityForResult. I am getting the expected result but am unsure how to respond to the result. What I'd like to do is call a different ArrayList (which is a resource) depending on the result.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle d = data.getExtras();
        String oil = d.getString("oil");
        Resources res = getResources();
        String[] oil_info = res.getStringArray(R.array.OIL);
        ...
    } 
}
```

I'd like R.array.OIL to change in response to the result. i.e. if `oil` = 'BASIL' change R.array.OIL to R.array.BASIL. I thought about making a hashmap but couldn't figure out how to put R.array.OIL into a hashmap as you cannot put primitives in a hashmap. I am pretty new to android and java so I'm sure there is a better way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getIdentifier()` for your requirement as below.

e.g. in array type 2 items are there as OIL and BASIL with different values.
you can access like R.array.OIL and R.array.BASIL.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle d = data.getExtras();
        String oil = d.getString("oil");
        Resources res = getResources();
        int id = res.getIdentifier(oil, "array", getPackageName());
        String[] oil_info = res.getStringArray(id);
        ...
    } 
}
```

In above code if string `oil` is `"OIL"` then `id` will become `R.array.OIL` and `oil` is `"BASIL"` then `id` will become `R.array.BASIL`

Comment: @NCAggie is it working for you, if not working clean the project before executing the app.

Comment: @NCAggie if you feel my answer is correct for your question, please mark it. this is how stackoverflow works. bye..

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying is actually an attempt of permanent storage . this is not allowed for "Res" folder or "R.smthing.smthing" data's . 
use `shared preferences` for primitive storage . 
see whether you can save array through `sharedPreferences` else use Serialization or SQLite database .